# Why aren't there any passed arguments to argv[]?

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, argv, argc

So, I noticed that my `argc` is always `1` as I will always get the message `Error: missing command line arguments!`, but as stated in code I am using `argv[1]` and `argv[2]` to read the files names.

Shouldn't automatically `argc` be `3` in this case, and to be able to pass that error?

Notes:

1. If I am not using `if (argc < 2)` statement, after I enter the name for the output file my program crushes.
2. For the input file I already have this one created in the project folder, so I just enter the name of that file.

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>   
#include <stdlib.h>

FILE *IN, *OUT;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2) 
    {
        printf("Error: missing command line arguments!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Enter the name of the file with the input data: ");
    scanf("%s", argv[1]);

    printf("\nEnter the name of the file for the output data: ");
    scanf("%s", argv[2]);

    IN = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    OUT = fopen(argv[2], "w");  

    fclose(IN);
    fclose(OUT);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you invoke your program? It's actually quite a crucial detail if you have problems with the programs arguments...

Comment: Is `argv` read only?

Comment: It seems like you have completely misunderstood what command line arguments are. You should not write to argv. It is a string array for the input arguments. Here is an example of how to use argc and argv: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/01/c-argc-argv/

Comment: @EdHeal - [It's perfectly fine to modify those arguments](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1p2), so long as the pointed-to memory is valid of course.

Comment: @EdHeal You can write to argv, but I cannot think of any good reason to do it.

Comment: Thank you, guys, all your questions and suggestions set me to do some more research and found a solution. I explained it all below in my comment to the answer of @Sourav Gosh.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're complete mis-understanding the purpose of `argc` and `argv`. They are supposed to receive the supplied command line argument (*program parameters*) before the program startup, not supposed to hold the *scannned* input at runtime.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §5.1.2.2.1,

> If they are declared, the parameters to the `main` function shall obey the following
>   constraints:
>
> — The value of `argc` shall be nonnegative.
>
> — `argv[argc]` shall be a null pointer.
>
> — If the value of `argc` is greater than zero, the array members `argv[0]` through
>   `argv[argc-1]` inclusive shall contain pointers to strings, which are given
>   implementation-defined values by the host environment prior to program startup. The
>   intent is to supply to the program information determined prior to program startup
>   from elsewhere in the hosted environment.

and

> If the value of `argc` is greater than zero, the string pointed to by `argv[0]`
>   represents the program name; `argv[0][0]` shall be the null character if the
>   program name is not available from the host environment. If the value of `argc` is
>   greater than one, the strings pointed to by `argv[1]` through `argv[argc-1]`
>   represent the program parameters.

To elaborate, when a program is invoked like

> ```
> ./a.out three total arguments
> ```

then, in your program

- `argc` will be 4
- `argv[0]` will be `./a.out`
- `argv[1]` will be `three`
- `argv[2]` will be `total`
- `argv[3]` will be `arguments`
- `argv[4]` will be `NULL` (see the property for `argv[argc]` above)

(*To generalize, `argv[1] - argv[argc-1]` will hold the supplied arguments, `argv[argc]` will be `NULL`*)

You don't need to explicitly *scan* the input, those values will be populated from the host environment.

On the other hand, you cannot just invoke the program like

> ```
> ./a.out
> ```

and *exptect* `argc` to be `3` (or any other value, other than 1, for that matter) and `argv[1]` - `argv[n-1]` to be *valid* because at compile-time the invokes program has no way to know that you *plan* to supply some values at runtime. It's not clairvoyant.

Comment: Thanks, it was really helpful for understanding how `argc` and `argv` works. I've done some more research and found a solution. I run the program in Code::Blocks 16.01, and found how to set the arguments for a file reading, or anything else for the matter.

Comment: For those interested of how to set arguments in Code::Blocks 16.01, you have to go in Project->Set Program Arguments. At Debug, in the text box named Program Arguments, one writes the arguments he wants to set to, knowing that the first argument written will coincide with `argv[1]`, since `argv[0]` is the source location of the program's executable.